# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Ive looked at atleast 8 other forums with the same title and none of the ones  read helped me at all!

So im using a partial to render a form to a `edit.html.erb` page and a `new.html.erb` page. My controller page works except for the edit page!

Here is my code for my controller page :

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their own profile.
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
      redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] )
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find( params[:id] )
    @profile = @user.profile 
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :job_title, :phone_number, :contact_email, :description)
  end
end
```

my `edit.html.erb` page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Edit Your Profile</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Be a part of the Dev Match community and fill out your profile!</p>
    <div class="well">
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my `new.html.erb` page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Your Profile</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Be a part of the Dev Match community and fill out your profile!</p>
    <div class="well">
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%=form_for (@profile) , url: user_profile_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :job_title %>
    <%= f.select :job_title, ['Developer', 'Entrepreneur', 'Investor'], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :contact_email %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @profile is nill or empty, and it can't be...

Comment: @BradWerth is it saying the User.profile is empty? im not understanding

Comment: it would certainly appear that way

Comment: @BradWerth i understand  , apprently my profile info got removed . So i created a new profile and when i cliked on edit this time it gave me a different error , " Couldn't find User with 'id'="

Answer (score 0):

You change your code into this:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly how i had it.

Comment: Currently you use `id` in to find user but the `id` parameter is a `id` of your profile. So you can use `params[:user_id]` equal with your `new` method.

Answer (score 0):

@user is null because the id does not exist in DB. 
If you create a new instance of `User` in the action `new` you can use the same object in the action `create` without use the method `User.find`

As improvement, try to add before_action in your controller.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :prepare_model, except: [:new, :create]

  def new
    # form where a user can fill out their own profile.
    @user = User.new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
      redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] )
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @profile = @user.profile 
  end

  private

  def prepare_model
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @user.nil?
  end

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :job_title, :phone_number, :contact_email, :description)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ill try this version as soon as i get home , the weird thing is that it started working with no changes.  I dont know how to trigger the error again. Thanks for your time.